# StringBuilder не работает как нужно

Tags: android, строки, broadcast-receiver, android-widgets

Занимаюсь созданием виджета. Делаю что-то наподобие нажатия на кнопку. Использую Broadcast. Предполагается, что после нажатия на определенную кнопку (в данном примере их 4), в экстра сохраняется какая-то текстовая переменная и присваивается броадкаст сообщение. В зависимости от этого, сообщения в StringBuilder записываю определенные экстра и передаю их виджету. Проблема в том, что StringBuilder не записывает эти экстрас по порядку. Например , есть 4 экстрас - 1,2,3,4 , мне необходима одна строка 1234, а у меня при каждом нажатии на кнопку выводится либо 1 либо 2 и тд. В чем ошибка, поставьте на путь истинный, пожалуйста.

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("");
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER2 = "ActionReceiverWidget2";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER3= "ActionReceiverWidget3";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER4 = "ActionReceiverWidget4";
private ComponentName thisWidget;




String msg4 = "null";



@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate " + Arrays.toString(appWidgetIds));
    //Создаем новый RemoteViews
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    //Подготавливаем Intent для Broadcast
    Intent active = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    active.putExtra("msg1", "1");
    //создаем наше событие
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
    //регистрируем наше событие
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, actionPendingIntent);


    //Подготавливаем Intent для Broadcast

    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER2);
    active.putExtra("msg2", "2");
    //создаем наше событие
    actionPendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
    //регистрируем наше событие
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, actionPendingIntent);

    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER3);
    active.putExtra("msg3", "+");
    //создаем наше событие
    actionPendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
    //регистрируем наше событие
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button4, actionPendingIntent);

    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER4);
    active.putExtra("msg4", "result");
    //создаем наше событие
    actionPendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
    //регистрируем наше событие
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button3, actionPendingIntent);
    //обновляем виджет
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    String msg;



    //Ловим наш Broadcast, проверяем и выводим сообщение
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    final String action = intent.getAction();



   switch (action){
        case "ActionReceiverWidget":
            msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg1");
            sb.append(intent.getStringExtra("msg1"));
            break;

        case "ActionReceiverWidget2":
            msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg2");
            sb.append(msg);
            break;

        case "ActionReceiverWidget3":
            msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg3");
            sb.append(msg);
            break;

        case "ActionReceiverWidget4":
            msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg4");
            sb.append(msg);
            break;
   }

    view.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, sb.toString());
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget,view);
        //Toast.makeText(context, msg4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

}

Comment: Пробовал, не получается.Странно то , что как только я произвожу операции с sb вне конструкции switch то все работает как нужно. Весь мозг сломал себе уже, не пойму , в чем дело

Answer (score 2):

Объясню, как работает ваш код:

1. `BroadcastReceiver` получает `Intent`, и вызывается `onReceive`.
2. Создается **новый** `StringBuilder`: `StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("");`
3. Вы добавляете в него кусочек текста: `sb.append(msg);`
4. Записываете текст во `View`: `view.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, sb.toString());`
5. Переходите к пункту 1.

То есть вам в 1 пункте не нужно создавать **новый** `StringBuilder`, а вынести его в поле.

Comment: Я вынес создание нового билдера в самое начало класса. Ничего не поменялось. Подскажите на пальцах, а то я в трех соснах заблудился:)с ума начинаю потихоньку сходить

Comment: @element111 покажите, как вы регистрируете ресивер, и куда вы вынесли создание билдера.

Comment: @element111, нет, добавьте код в вопрос. И это не весь код, который я просил.

Comment: добавил весь класс

Comment: @element111, судя по вашему коду, все теперь должно работать правильно. Попробуйте сделать ребилд проекта, возможно обновления  просто не установились. Если вы используете instant run, лучше его отключите, т. к. он работает пока ужасно

Comment: Должно, я тоже это понимаю , но не работает)) ребилд пробывал....странно почему билдер работает если заполнять его вручную, вне switch.

Comment: @element111, Ну понаблюдайте в дебаге, расставьте брейкпоинтов, возможно у вас логика самого switch Неправильная...

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать

Comment: `static StringBuilder sb; if(sb==null) sb = new StringBuilder("");` попробуй так.

Comment: @santavital Спасибо большое за дельный совет. все заработало как надо. Только вот интересно почему билдер до этого создавался заного всегда...

Comment: Рад что помогло ... на всякий случай когда виджет завершает работу (окончательно) добавь `if(sb!=null) sb = null` чтобы память освободить

Comment: @santavital Такой вопрос, спустя какое то время билдер сам по себе обнуляется(или новый создается, не знаю), а минут через 10- 15 виджет вообще перестает реагировать на нажатия...есть идеи?